# Error using Qt and unique pointers

Tags: c++, qt, unique-ptr

I am currently working on an interface for an random application. In the interface I have a `QListView`, which have three buttons related to it. The first one is add, which adds a new item on the widget, this button works fine. The problem comes with the clear button:

```
void NeuralNetwork::on_clearButton_clicked() {
    this->model.get()->clear();
    this->item.clear();
}
```

as you see both model and item are attributes of this class. They are declared as this:

```
std::unique_ptr<QStandardItemModel> model = unique_ptr<QStandardItemModel>(new QStandardItemModel());
vector<unique_ptr<QStandardItem>> item;
```

Initially I was using normal pointers, but as I searched on the internet, people were recommending using unique pointers to handle memory management.

I think there is something wrong with

```
this->model.get()
```

but I don't know exactly, since I have no experience with smart pointers. Note that the program doesn't get build errors, it works fine until I press the clear button on the interface, then the program crashes:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: What do you use `this->model.get()` for ?

Comment: 2. Do you put `QStandardItemModel` on the form and set its parent ?

Comment: as I understand, model.get() returns me a pointer to the object, so then I can use its methods. But now I think I will drop smart pointers and use normal pointers instead, since Werner Erasmus said that it is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be carefull, as QStandardItemModel has ownership of standard items. Therefore you would get a double delete when you associated a standard item with a unique pointer.

In general, with Qt you don't need to use unique pointers, as parents already have ownership of their children.

Comment: Ok. I will keep that in mind. Now I am just using normal pointers and it is working fine, I was just afraid to have some memory problems in the future.