# Error deleting a pointer in a vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qlistview

I am getting trouble trying to delete a pointer that is owned by a vector. In my application I have a QListView, and I store new items based on a vector of pointers. This is the declaration:

```
private:
vector<QStandardItem *> item; 
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();
```

I simplified it, but it is an attribute of a class. To add new items I use this code:

```
this->item.push_back(new QStandardItem());
for (unsigned long i = 0; i != this->item.size(); ++i) {
    this->item[i]->setCheckable( true );
    this->item[i]->setCheckState( Qt::Checked );
    this->item[i]->setText( "Current " + QString::number(i) );
    this->model->setItem( i, this->item[i] );
    ui->listView->setModel( model );
}
```

This works just fine. Now I am trying to add a delete button which deletes the current index on the QListView. This is the code I made so far:

```
QModelIndex index = ui->listView->currentIndex();
int deleteIndex = index.row();
this->model->removeRow(deleteIndex);
delete this->item[deleteIndex];
this->item.erase(this->item.begin() + deleteIndex);
```

For what I searched on StackOverflow, the line

```
delete this->item[deleteIndex];
```

should work, but I am getting an application crash every time I press the delete button. Without that line the button works fine, the problem is that I am not deallocating the memory used by that item.

EDIT: I already made a question related to the same problem.
[[Error using Qt and unique pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631923/error-using-qt-and-unique-pointers][1])

Now I am wondering if I am trying to delete the pointer two times, and thats why I am getting the error. The problem is that my knowledge about c++ and qt is not very high.

Comment: Huh I have no idea what `qlistview` is but if it is `std::vector`, shouldn't you use `this->item.erase(this->item.begin() + deleteIndex)` before freeing memory of the item?

Comment: for what I have seen in another examples they initially deleted first, but I will try

Comment: @mostruash that's not the issue: the vector is storing pointers, it (the vector) doesn't care if the pointer is pointing to a valid address or not

Comment: Perhaps `this->model->removeRow(deleteIndex);` deletes the `QStandardItem`.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I thought that `vector` is probably data bound to some qt mumbo jumbo (`qlistview`). `vector` doesn't care but if something else uses the vector for listing items in a list, then there's a problem.

Comment: haha places one should use shared_ptr ++

Comment: @lhahn according to the SO question you provided and to Jens' answer, you shouldn't delete them manually, it seems that Qt does memory management for you.

Comment: yes It looks like, but he said generally, so I didn't know if it would be all the time.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to ask that specifically, when to delete and when not to. edit your tags to include qt.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Completely wrong assertion. Qt is NOT a place where you should use shared_ptr as it has its own memory management for many of its objects (IIRC, not all though).

Comment: @JBL you misunderstood: Qt should be using shared_ptr (or unique_ptr) to indicate via signature the /fact/ it's managing the object

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Oh ok. Still, that wouldn't be of any use IMO as you don't have any idea of how the memory is managed internally when you use Qt as a client.

Comment: Qt manages your data, so you don't need to. Remove `item` and all associated code. Use `getItem` when needed. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually deleting a second time the `QStandardItem` that was at this index. Indeed, as you can see in the following extract from the Qt doc of the [`QStandardItemModel`'s function `setItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItem)

> Sets the item for the given row and column to item. **The model takes ownership of the item**. If necessary, the row count and column count are increased to fit the item. **The previous item at the given location (if there was one) is deleted.**

the `QStandardItemModel` manages any `QStandardItem` you would pass it, and thus you should never try to delete these.

As a rule of thumb, when you're unsure, check the Qt documentation for any function where you pass a `QObject`. If it says it take ownership, then never delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Qt is managing the lifetime of the objects through a parent-child relationship and automatically deletes children. This was at least the case Qt while I was using it. Considering that, I think there is no need for manual memory management here because the item will be deleted by Qt.

Comment: Ahh, that was about what I posted on my edit. But would be nice if someone could confirm that, I will try searching about the issue

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Memory-management looks like a good place to start. To quote from one of the links: "Qt’s parent-child mechanism is implemented in QObject. When we create an object (a widget, validator, or any other kind) with a parent, the parent adds the object tothe list of its children. When the parent is deleted, it walks through its list of children and deletes each child."